# VBA Sort Union on a multiple range selection

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I get the run-time error '1004' when running a sort macro on a multiple range selection. I'm new at VBA and using Application.Union hasn't helped.

```
Sub Sort()

    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim RR As Range
    Set R1 = Range("B12:C31") 'Page One
    Set R2 = Range("B47:C66") 'Page Two, etc.
    Set RR = Union2(R1, R2)
    RR.Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

I need to sort names (Column C) associated with numbers (Column B) on multiple printed pages. I've seen other people solve the singe range sort problem by listing the names and numbers on one continuous page.

EDIT:

Hiding rows, sorting, and unhiding rows works where trying to sort Application.Union doesn't.

```
Sub Sort()
    Rows("32:46").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Dim oneRange As Range
    Set oneRange = Range("B12:C66")
    oneRange.Sort Key1:=Range("C12"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Rows("32:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I wish there was a way to sort multiple ranges so a macro isn't needed.

Comment: as the error message is telling you, you can't use `Sort()` on a multiple range. You could copy/paste them into a contiguous range and then sort this letter

Comment: I'm now trying to create a macro to hide rows, sort, then unhide rows.